# I need to merge two separate queries using CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I need to merge these two separate queries using the CASE statement. My overall objective is "I am looking to find all locations that are live and live no charge, that are not demos. These locations MUST be located in the US or Canada. Find out how many customers in these locations have their country filled out that is NOT US or Canada, as opposed to how many total customers they have."

So I have both queries written out, and they both work separately.

Here is the first one that returns customers NOT in the US.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS "Not in US or Canada verse Total Customers" 
FROM 
    dbo.Spa (nolock)
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.Customer ON dbo.Customer.SpaID = dbo.Spa.ID
WHERE 
    dbo.Spa.TimeZoneID IN (6, 9, 12, 18) 
    AND dbo.Spa.IsDeleted = 0
    AND dbo.Spa.StatusID IN (3, 4)
    AND dbo.Customer.CountryID != 1
    AND dbo.Customer.countryID != 2;
```

Here is the second one that returns ALL customers.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS "Total Customers" 
FROM 
    dbo.Spa (nolock)
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.Customer ON dbo.Customer.SpaID = dbo.Spa.ID
WHERE 
    dbo.Spa.TimeZoneID IN (6, 9, 12, 18) 
    AND dbo.Spa.IsDeleted = 0
    AND dbo.Spa.StatusID IN (3, 4);
```

Can anyone help me put these together using a case statement where it will show customers NOT in US and Canada verse total Customers in one table using CASE statement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question right, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT      COUNT(1) AS "All customers",
            SUM(CASE WHEN (dbo.Customer.CountryID != 1 AND dbo.Customer.countryID != 2)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Not in US or Canada verse Total Customers"
FROM        dbo.Spa (nolock)
LEFT JOIN   dbo.Customer    ON  dbo.Customer.SpaID = dbo.Spa.ID
WHERE       dbo.Spa.TimeZoneID IN(6,9,12,18) 
AND         dbo.Spa.IsDeleted= 0
AND         dbo.Spa.StatusID IN (3,4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a case expression.

```
SELECT sum(case when dbo.Customer.CountryID <> 1 AND dbo.Customer.countryID <> 2 then 1 end) as NotInUS
    , COUNT(1) AS "Not in US or Canada verse Total Customers" 
FROM dbo.Spa (nolock)
LEFT JOIN dbo.Customer ON dbo.Customer.SpaID = dbo.Spa.ID
WHERE dbo.Spa.TimeZoneID IN(6,9,12,18) 
AND dbo.Spa.IsDeleted= 0
AND dbo.Spa.StatusID IN (3,4)
```

Also, you should probably get out of the habit of splattering NOLOCK all over the place. It has some very serious and often misunderstood side effects. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 0):

You can just make each query a subselect:

```
SELECT (query1) as '', (query2) as ''
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first query you use a left join but then filter on `CountryID` which would eliminated `Spa` rows that didn't have a matching country. There may in fact not be any but you should be aware that you could get different counts in the grand total as a result of that change. If there can be no more than one customer per "Spa"(?) then joining to that table (in the 2nd query) doesn't even accomplish anything but it's hard to guess if you intended to do that.

```
select
    count(case when c.CountryID not in (1, 2) then 1 else null end),
    count(*)
from
    dbo.Spa as s
    left outer join dbo.Customer as c
        on c.SpaID = s.SpaID
where
        s.TimeZoneID in (6, 9, 12, 18)
    and s.IsDeleted = 0
    and s.StatusID in (3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to use a CASE statement in a COUNT() to only count a specified group:

```
    WITH
    /*
    Get a list of all customers and their country to use as the main data set as an example
    */
    mainSet AS
        (
        SELECT
            contact.FirstName,
            address.city,
            stateProvince.countryRegionCode 
        FROM person.address AS address
        INNER JOIN sales.customerAddress AS customerAddress ON
            address.addressID = customerAddress.addressID
        INNER JOIN sales.customer AS customer ON
            customerAddress.customerID = customer.customerID
        INNER JOIN person.contact AS contact ON 
            customer.customerID = contact.contactID
        INNER JOIN person.stateProvince AS stateProvince ON
            address.stateProvinceID = stateProvince.stateProvinceID
        )

    SELECT
        --------------------------------------------------Count all customers using COUNT()
        COUNT(countryRegionCode) AS 'All Customers Count',

        --------------------------------------------------Count all customers using COUNT() with a CASE statement
        COUNT(CASE WHEN countryRegionCode NOT IN('US','CA') THEN countryRegionCode END) AS 'Customers not in US/CA'
    FROM mainSet
```